# PureCSS vertical center/middle div elements

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I'm trying to center my div elements (PureCSS) to build a grid like this (100% width and height, no scrollbar):

[image: Container]

Now I need to align all the elements vertically and horizontally centered.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="pure-g" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="pure-u-1-5" style="height:90%;">
        <div class="pure-g" style="height:50%;">
          <div class="pure-u-1-1 visible"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:100%;"></div>
          <div class="pure-u-1-1 visible"><img src="img/ad.png" alt="AD" style="width:100%;"></div>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-4-5" style="height:90%;">
        <div class="pure-g" style="height:100%;">

          <div class="pure-u-1-1" style="height:20%;">
            <div class="pure-g" style="height:100%;">
              <div class="pure-u-1-6 news"><p>PIC</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-1-3 news"><p>TITLE</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-5-12 news"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-1-12 news"><p>ID</p></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pure-u-1-1" style="height:20%;">
            <div class="pure-g" style="height:100%;">
              <div class="pure-u-1-6 news"><p>PIC</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-1-3 news"><p>TITLE</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-5-12 news"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-1-12 news"><p>ID</p></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pure-u-1-1" style="height:20%;">
            <div class="pure-g" style="height:100%;">
              <div class="pure-u-1-6 news"><p>PIC</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-1-3 news"><p>TITLE</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-5-12 news"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-1-12 news"><p>ID</p></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pure-u-1-1" style="height:20%;">
            <div class="pure-g" style="height:100%;">
              <div class="pure-u-1-6 news"><p>PIC</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-1-3 news"><p>TITLE</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-5-12 news"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-1-12 news"><p>ID</p></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="pure-u-1-1" style="height:20%;">
            <div class="pure-g" style="height:100%;">
              <div class="pure-u-1-6 news"><p>PIC</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-1-3 news"><p>TITLE</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-5-12 news"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div>
              <div class="pure-u-1-12 news"><p>ID</p></div>
            </div>
          </div>       

        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1-1 marquee">NEWSTICKER (jQuery marquee)</div>
    </div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
*{font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;}

h1, h2, h3, p {color:#fff;}

body, html {
    overflow:hidden;
  height: 100%;
  padding:0px;
}

div {
  /*
  border:1px solid;
  margin:-1px;
  */
}

.news {
  height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:#444; background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.visible {
  height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:#444; background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.news p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:15px;
  height:100%;
}

.marquee {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:#444; background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
    border-radius:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
}
```

The result is this:
[image: Container_now]

I read some threads for this problem but none of them seemed to work for me getting the div elements vertically centered.
I would also be glad if any of you finds some code improvement since this is my first time building a grid like this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your `.news p` has a height of 100% to a parent with `height:100%` .. Use a PX height and assign the line height to be the same.

Comment: Hi @Pogrindis thanks, you're right. But changing it doesn't solve my original problem, the items are still positioned on top. The height has to be in percent (right side: 90%, inside 5x20%) to make it as responsive as possible

Comment: Isnt pureCSS already responsive with built in definitions ?

Comment: For the width yes, but not the height. The page has to fill the screen vertically and horizontally with no scrollbar

Comment: Thats a dangerous task.. Hard to guarantee you wont ever need a scrollbar!

Comment: This way I can't, but for my case I need this page for Infoscreens at 720p and 1080p TVs

Answer (score 1):

This is the CSS / HTML I use to center stuff vertically and horizontally:

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.center-outter {
    display: table; 
    position: absolute; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
}
.center-middle { 
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
.center-inner { 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    /*width:200px;*/
}

.whatever {
    width:200px; 
    background:#efefef;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="center-outter">
        <div class="center-middle">
            <div class="center-inner whatever">
                <div>This should be centered vertically and horizontally</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple, no 3rd party.

This the basic frame work I'd use.

I would not make the images scalable.  Too much work for those wimpy ARM processors in smartphones.  I'd fix the width of the left column and pic div

I put temporary colored borders on the divs.

**CSS**

```
#col1{width:14%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
#col2{width:84%;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;}
#logo{width:200px;height:200px;}
.row{width:100%;border:4px solid #000;display:inline-block;}
.pic{width:15%;border:1px solid #00f;display:inline-block;}
.title{width:30%;border:1px solid #f00;display:inline-block;}
.desc{width:40%;border:1px solid #0ff;display:inline-block;}
.id{width:10%;border:1px solid #f0f;display:inline-block;}
#marquee{height:6em;}<br>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="col1">
<div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo"></div>
<div id="ad"><img src="img/ad.png" alt="AD" ></div>
</div>
<div id="col2">
<div class="row"><div class="pic"><p>PIC</p></div><div class="title"><p>TITLE</p></div><div class="desc"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div><div class="id"><p>ID</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="pic"><p>PIC</p></div><div class="title"><p>TITLE</p></div><div class="desc"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div><div class="id"><p>ID</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="pic"><p>PIC</p></div><div class="title"><p>TITLE</p></div><div class="desc"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div><div class="id"><p>ID</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="pic"><p>PIC</p></div><div class="title"><p>TITLE</p></div><div class="desc"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div><div class="id"><p>ID</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="pic"><p>PIC</p></div><div class="title"><p>TITLE</p></div><div class="desc"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div><div class="id"><p>ID</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="pic"><p>PIC</p></div><div class="title"><p>TITLE</p></div><div class="desc"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div><div class="id"><p>ID</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="pic"><p>PIC</p></div><div class="title"><p>TITLE</p></div><div class="desc"><p>DESCRIPTION</p></div><div class="id"><p>ID</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div id="marquee">Breaking News</div></div></div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late response and thank you very much for the simplification. I'm always a fan of keeping things simple. I tried and like your solution, but how do I get #col2 to use 100% of the available height? Thanks in advance

Comment: The number of rows and their height determine the height.  The height of each row is determined by font size and padding.  The problem is you will never know the height of the client window.  I use my monitors in portrait mode and my height is 1920px. According to Statcounter, currently the most popular height is  768px.  Your desire to have no scroll bars, use 100% of available height, and no JavaSript is probably unrealistic as it is dependent on the client window height.